# Indian languages are not working in Pdfmake in ionic1

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, pdfmake

I am creating a pdf file using pdfmake in ionic1 in which i would like to download the pdf in indian languages(Tamil). I have added custom fonts for tamil language also but when i try to download the pdf i am getting boxes.
can anyone tell me how to use Indianlanguages(Tamil) for pdf file using Ionic.

Pdf creation:

```
function createPdf(invoice) {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            var dd = createDocumentDefinition(invoice);
            pdfMake.fonts = {
               TSCu_SaiIndira: {
                 normal: 'TSCu_SaiIndira.ttf',
                 bold: 'TSCu_SaiIndira.ttf',
                 italics: 'TSCu_SaiIndira.ttf',
                 bolditalics: 'TSCu_SaiIndira.ttf'
                }
            }
            var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);

            pdf.getBase64(function (output) {
                resolve(base64ToUint8Array(output));
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps for adding custom fonts...??

Comment: @AkshaySoam i have updated the plugin and it is working fine